# what is the difference between global and instance mutex in python

Tags: python, mutex

what is the difference between using mutex as a global variable or as an instance variable?
for example, these two usages?:

```
my_lock = RLock()
class myclass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.mutex = my_lock
    def func():
        with self.mutex:
            #do something
```

and

```
class myclass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.mutex = RLock()
    def func():
        with self.mutex:
            #do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first version;

```
my_lock = RLock()
class myclass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.mutex = my_lock
```

...creates a single mutex common to all instances of the class, while

```
class myclass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.mutex = RLock()
```

...creates a mutex per instance.

In the first case, the mutex blocks `func` from executing simultaneously in *any* myclass object.

In the second case, the mutex blocks `func` from executing simultaneously in a *single* myclass object.